# Upload doesn't work using Carrierwave in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I was working on my app and trying to put on an uploader feature.

First I generated a course uploader and allowed jpeg, jpg, png and gif.

Next I've added the ff code mount on my course model:

```
  mount_uploader :thumb_image, CoursesUploader
  mount_uploader :main_image, CoursesUploader
```

Next, I place the file upload form code on my new.html.erb file:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :main_image %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
  <%= f.file_field :thumb_image %>
</div>
```

And when I tried to submit my form with my images uploaded it did not even show the index page instead I refresh the page and then see if it got uploaded and the form was submitted successfully but it did not.

I also look at the strong params on my controller and these two items are there:

```
  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def course_params
      params.require(:course).permit(:title, :price, :body, :main_image, :thumb_image)
    end
```

Any idea what am I missing here?

Here's something I got from my terminal after submission:

```
Started POST "/courses" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-16 20:52:20 +0800
Processing by CoursesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wlKpv8czsuC6AZjCctxYk203wry4cb0dnOYI9IoAkzRZNV2vB4/vREU5L5u4G7vh5ZhCbHZlJ6nHPN95qO+cbA==", "course"=>{"title"=>"Goody", "price"=>"33", "main_image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f81e52eed48 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/3_/8bmsd3j13bxfdl1jp7gzvvsm0000gn/T/RackMultipart20190116-2359-17w6pb.jpg>, @original_filename="61230.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"course[main_image]\"; filename=\"61230.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "thumb_image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f81e52eecd0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/3_/8bmsd3j13bxfdl1jp7gzvvsm0000gn/T/RackMultipart20190116-2359-2mcy4i.jpg>, @original_filename="61230.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"course[thumb_image]\"; filename=\"61230.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "body"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Course"}
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/courses_controller.rb:27
  Course Exists (1.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "courses" WHERE "courses"."id" IS NOT NULL AND "courses"."slug" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["slug", "goody"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/courses_controller.rb:27
   (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/courses_controller.rb:27
  Rendering courses/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered courses/new.html.erb within layouts/application (12.6ms)
  Rendered shared/_application_nav.html.erb (6.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_application_footer.html.erb (1.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 394ms (Views: 356.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
```

UPDATE: FULL MODEL CONTENT

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  include DefaultsConcern

  enum status: { draft: 0, published: 1 }
  validates_presence_of :title, :price, :body, :main_image, :thumb_image

  mount_uploader :thumb_image, CoursesUploader
  mount_uploader :main_image, CoursesUploader

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

end
```

FULL FORM CONTENT:

```
<h1>New Form</h1>

<%= form_for(@course) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %>
    <%= f.number_field :price %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :main_image %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
  <%= f.file_field :thumb_image %>
</div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you show course model?

Comment: main_image and thumb_image are supposed to different images? or the same but different size?

Comment: Updated my answer and shown full model. atGabbar
atNEL for this time just free sizes

Answer (score 0):

Validation failed as `params[:course][:body]` is `nil` due to which ***creating course rolled back***

```
validates_presence_of :title, :price, :body, :main_image, :thumb_image
```

=> So just **fillup** `body` field in form or **remove** `validates_presence_of :body`

Comment: I am not sure why the body is nil but I place some content on it upon submission. I need to put it on the presence as this is required.

Comment: @MarcSolva As i can't see form so it won't possible to figure out where is missing but it's for sure due to `failing body field validation` it's rolled back.

Comment: @MarcSolva is body `string` or `text` type column?

Comment: @MarcSolva Are you performing some javascript stuffs on form submission to make body blank ? can you cross check it?

Comment: its text field on scheme `t.text "body"`

Comment: Nope just pure rails there. Haven't added any verification or javascript stuffs yet.

Comment: @MarcSolva Hmm other than this your form look good, it should send body value with form data. but your sever logs show `"body" => ""`

Comment: So I tried to put an error message and it saying "Main image can't be blank
Thumb image can't be blank"

Comment: @MarcSolva Not sure but it rolls back just only cause of validation and as i can see you have whitelisted main_image and thumb_image and form is also sending these data.

Comment: Yeah no luck sigh.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the Image is ActionDispatch already but are you sure you created your table column like this -Regardless of creating table or adding_column-

I'm focusing on

```
:string, array: true, default: []
```

Migration should look like:

```
add_column :courses, :main_image, :string, array: true, default: []
```

As creating the column as String won't let carrierwave add it's object as an array inside it, so it should be an array

Also you can set thumb and main images in one uploader if you are going to change the size only, otherwise you're fine to use :thumb_image and :main_image but make sure the migration is correct

If you can't change it, just drop and re-create it

Comment: Trying this out one second.

Comment: Take your time, hopefully it helps you :)

Comment: So I tried this and re-created the main image but did not work still. According to the error I place on the form it says "Main image cant be blank"

Comment: Really hard. It keeps on asking about the image

Comment: Can you please provice the part of the schema file which shows this table?